# MySql, search with LIKE %str%

Tags: mysql

I search my table with query contains LIKE clause %str%.

Is here a way to know where string 'str' was finded in sentence?

I would like to print out 'str' as markup (bold).

For this I need information where exact 'str' begins in any row which contain 'str'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the string position using the POSITION function ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_position ) however thats probably not the best way to do it since if they use the markup more than once it will only return the first position.  It would be easier just to replace the string with the string wrapped with whatever markup you want.

If you want an all MySQL solution this would probably work:

```
SELECT REPLACE(exampleTable.field, 'search_string', '<b>search_string</b>')
FROM exampleTable
WHERE exampleTable.field LIKE '%search_string%';
```

However i would recommend doing any replacement like this on the PHP / ASP side... using string replacement tools from the respective language.

Comment: Thany jakraska. SELECT DTBL_ID, mjj, kolic, prodano, name, sb, prodajnac FROM invlista WHERE name LIKE '%max%' ORDER BY name. This is exact query I already have. On this example I would like to bold word 'max' in column 'name'. Your advice looks interesting. Can it be applyed on described situation and how?

Comment: Forget to say, I uses this from C on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I find how to implement this: SELECT DTBL_ID, mjj, kolic, prodano, REPLACE(name, '", "str", "', '<b>", "str", "</b>'), sb, prodajnac FROM"..., and it works! Now, only one problem remains. 'Str' is case sensitive. How can I make it case insensitive?

Comment: MySQL does not have support for case-insensitive string replacement by default.  See this link for a custom function you can add http://pento.net/2009/02/15/case-insensitive-replace-for-mysql/

However again, this is why i would recommend doing the string replacement on the scripting language side (PHP/ASP/PERL, etc) rather than in MySQL - other languages have much more robust string tools and can handle this easily.

Comment: I understand now. Replacing out of MySql could be time consumpting I suppose. Additionaly, I use C and my MySql strings is utf8 so here is also problem to replace utf8 strings. Thanx for helping, I will still see what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you want [INSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) .
You could also use it in your where clause, though you'd want to compare performance between that and LIKE

```
SELECT INSTR(`field`, 'str') FROM `table` WHERE 0 < INSTR(`field`, 'str')
```

Remember that INSTR() returns a 1-based index, that is, the first character is postion 1, not position 0; saving 0 for "not found".

Comment: Thany for advice umbrella. I already have query and query results. Can I incorporate this in my existing query?